# Samba server not taking credentials on a windows machine

Tags: windows-7, permissions, network-shares, samba, ubuntu-14.04

I had a series of problems with samba server.
I have a ubuntu server 14.04 installed here on the office. I installed the samba server, and it worked correctly with a test folder. Then i installed a new Hard Drive with 4tb (my cliente wanted that much space) so after i installed the HD, and tryied to make samba share a folder on the Hard drive (which is mounted under /media/cincamesoporte/sharing/) i had no succes.
I revised the documentation and it says that i had to use chcon:

```
chcon -t samba_share_t /var/eng
```

but it throw me an error, saying that i can't add a tag in a partial context.
So i want ahead and keep reading and i read that i had to use semanage.

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/var/eng(/.*)?"
```

But it throw me another error that it can't use the policy.
Later i found a solution for this:
i read that a person used a force user = username in the smb.conf of the samba server and it FINALLY worked. So i can check the files under that folder, and the i created another folder which it's supposed to be secured, only one person has to have access to this specific folder, so i created the user

```
$ useradd example
$ passwd example
```

also i created a group with

```
$groupadd examplegroup
```

then i added the user to the group:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G examplegroup example
```

after all that, i went to the smb.conf and started using this configuration:

```
[global] 
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
```

then i have the sahring folders, the first one it's for public access, and the second one it's the one that only my client have access to.

```
[Archivos Compartidos]


comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
  path = /media/cincamesoporte/sharing/public_folder
  browsable = yes
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 0755
  force user = myuser

[Doctor]
  path = /media/cincamesoporte/sharing/doctor_folder
  guest ok = no
  writable = yes
  browsable = yes
  valid users = @examplegroup
```

and i created a password for the user with:

```
smbpasswd example
```

and after all that, i went to login with windows, and it asks me for username and password, but it says:

"\\Server\Folder it's not accessible, you might not have permission to use this network resource.Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have permissions or not.

Multiple connections to the server or shared resources using more than one user name are not allowed.Disconect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again".

So this is my problem, and i have been working on this for a few hours now, and i'm running out of ideas. Any help would be REALLY appretiated. Thanks in andvance!

Comment: As far as I know ubuntu 14.04 dosen't use selinux by default - I've never had to use semanage and chcon on ubuntu. Also, if its for public access, why are you forcing a user?

Comment: Like i said, one folder it's for public access, and the second one it's for private access.

Comment: OHH! And the force user? For some reason, it doesnt work because it's not a /home folder without it.

Comment: Wierd. http://pastebin.com/61q5CRkn works for me and its a pretty minimal setup

Comment: Man sorry for the long wait, i had to leave the work place and i dont have access to the server, im gonna keep trying on monday. Thanks for you time dude!